# Comparing names from tkinter Entry to sqlite3 table

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

I am wondering how to compare the entry into a tkinter window to data in a sqlite3 table. I am able to read from the table but when compared to an "Entry" it never comes out as if the entry has been found.

```
def __init__(self, master):
self.frame = Frame(master)
self.frame.pack()
self.firstname = StringVar()
self.surname = StringVar()

 def find(self):
    x = c.execute('SELECT surname FROM MemberRecordsTable')
    if self.surname.get() == x:
        found = Label(self.frame, text = 'Name found')
        found.pack()
    else:
        notfound = Label(self.frame, text = 'Name not found')
        notfound.pack()

def checkpayments(self):
    checkmember = Entry(self.frame, textvariable = self.surname)
    checkmember.pack()
    checkmember2 = Entry(self.frame, textvariable = self.firstname)
    checkmember2.pack()
    findmember = Button(self.frame, text = 'Find member', command = self.find)
    findmember.pack()
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you tried printing out `x` to see if it is what you assume it is?

Answer (score 1):

[`cursor.execute()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.execute) returns a [`sqlite3.Cursor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor) object. You then need to use that cursor to get the actual query results. You could do that with [`cursor.fetchone()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone) to grab the first result.

However, since you want to check if there are any rows in the database containing the value of `self.surname` in the surname column you can query like this:

```
c.execute('SELECT surname FROM MemberRecordsTable where surname = ?', (self.surname.get(),))
if c.fetchone():
    print('Found')
else:
    print('Not found')
```

This query will return rows from the database having the value of `self.surname` in the `surname` column. The query is performed using parametrisation to mitigate against SQL injection attacks which are present when accepting arbitrary user entered data.